# How to reload tableView in titanium?

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, reload

my code is

```
     var tableData=[];
     var dict ={};
        dict["title"] ='My Title';
        tableData[0] =dict;



 var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
            data:tableData,
        });
  self.add(table);
```

This data is displayed properly.

Then in some function i am updating the array.

```
  var dict ={};
    dict["title"] ='My New Title';
    dict["hasChild"]=true;
  tableData[0] =dict;
```

And setting table data using setData:

```
table.setData(tableData);
```

But there is no changes in tableView, i searched  similar questions but din't get any help.

Comment: show some more code ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work... Before you set the updated data, make the tableView empty with a blank array and then update again with new data.

```
table.setData([]);
table.setData(tableData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove first all the objects from the array and then update your array object and after then reload the table with `table.setData(tableData);`

Comment: No need to remove, setData would be fine :)

Comment: @Maulik then something else is wrong. The setdata is probably not called

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the Table Data with `table.data = tableData;`
In some Cases you need to re-set the Data with `table.setData( table.data );`